# How to turn a function into async

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, async-await, google-cloud-firestore

I'll start out by saying I have little to no experience building async functions, and after reading the documentation on it I am even more confused.

I am using vue.js as the framework and my methods make calls to firebase.

**Goal**

The problem is that with firebase when you delete a document it doesn't automatically delete all nested documents, you have to do it manually with recursive functions. So I had to recreate the delete function to accomplish this and did so by making a mixin. The mixin now works, however, the reload emit event now fires before the delete function has completed and as a result, a ghost element remains in the DOM.

I want `$emit('reload')` to not fire until all calls to firebase in `deleteProject()` have finished.

**My Code**

```
<script>
import { deleteProject } from '../../../mixins/deleteData'

export default {
  mixins: [deleteProject],
  props: ['yearId', 'projectId', 'project'],
  name: 'deleteProjectModal',
  data: () => ({
    dialog: false
  }),
  methods: {
    del () {
      // call deleteYear method from mixin
      this.deleteProject(this.yearId, this.projectId)
      // emit reload signal for database relaod
      this.$emit('reload')
      // close modal
      this.dialog = false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```
import firebase from '@/firebase/init'

export const deleteProject = {
  methods: {
    deleteProject (yearId, projectId) {
      // delete project, all documents in the images subcollection of the project, and all stored images
      firebase.firestore().collection('years').doc(yearId).collection('projects').doc(projectId).get()
        .then((doc) => {
          // delete thumbnail
          firebase.storage().ref(doc.data().thumbFullPath).delete()
          // delete project document
          firebase.firestore().collection('years').doc(yearId).collection('projects').doc(projectId).delete()
          firebase.firestore().collection('years').doc(yearId).collection('projects').doc(projectId).collection('images').get()
            .then((querySnapshot) => {
              querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                // delete gallery image
                this.imagePaths.append(doc.data().fullPath)
                // delete reference document for gallery image
                doc.ref.delete()
              })
            })
        })
    }
  }
}
```

**What I have tried**

I assume the solution would revolve around turning `deleteProject()` into an async function and calling `deleteProject().then($emit('reload'))`. However, I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

**Edit**

As requested, `reload` triggers the following function:

```
import firebase from '@/firebase/init'

export const loadGallery = {
  data: () => ({
    years: []
  }),
  methods: {
    loadProjects () {
      var years = []
      var temp = []
      firebase.firestore().collection('years').orderBy('year', 'desc').onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((year) => {
          firebase.firestore().collection('years').doc(year.id).collection('projects').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((project) => {
              var objectMicro = { title: project.data().title, thumbUrl: project.data().thumbUrl, route: project.data().route, id: project.id }
              temp.push(objectMicro)
            })
          }).then(() => {
            var objectMacro = { year: year.data().year, id: year.id, projects: temp }
            years.push(objectMacro)
            temp = []
          })
        })
      })
      this.years = years
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, are you still having the problem? I.e. are you still seeking some help? Please answer with @RenaudTarnec

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I still have not found a solution to the problem, so yes still seeking help. My current hack fix has been to create a button which a user can press to manually fire ```reload``` once the delete function has run.

Comment: Have a look at the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing several asynchronous Firebase operations in your `deleteProject` method (calling Firestore [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#get), Firestore [`delete()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#delete), Cloud Storage [`delete()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#delete), ...) but you are not correctly chaining the different Promises returned by these Firebase methods.

You have to chain those Promises with the [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method , which "returns a Promise which allows for method chaining".

So, the following should do the trick (untested however):

```
export const deleteProject = {
   methods: {     
      deleteProject (yearId, projectId) {
      // delete project, all documents in the images subcollection of the project, and all stored images
      return firebase.firestore().collection('years').doc(yearId).collection('projects').doc(projectId).get()
        .then((doc) => {
          // delete thumbnail
          return firebase.storage().ref(doc.data().thumbFullPath).delete()
        })
       .then(() => {
          return firebase.firestore().collection('years').doc(yearId).collection('projects').doc(projectId).delete();
       })
       .then(() => {
          return firebase.firestore().collection('years').doc(yearId).collection('projects').doc(projectId).collection('images').get()
       })
       .then((querySnapshot) => {
          const promises = [];
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            // delete gallery image
            this.imagePaths.append(doc.data().fullPath)
            // delete reference document for gallery image
            promises.push(doc.ref.delete());
          })
          return Promise.all(promises);
       })
      }
  }
}
```

And since this `deleteProject()` method is now asynchronous, you need to call it as follows in your mixin:

```
  methods: {
    del () {
      // call deleteYear method from mixin
      this.deleteProject(this.yearId, this.projectId)
      .then(() => {
         // emit reload signal for database relaod
         this.$emit('reload')
         // close modal
         this.dialog = false
      })
    }
  }
```

---

Note that we use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to execute in parallel all the `delete()` method calls in the `forEach()`. `Promise.all()` method returns a single Promise that fulfills when all of the promises passed to as an iterable (i.e. the `promises` array) have been fulfilled.

Comment: The problem with this is that it the delete operations now only delete the project document and none of its nested documents or the images. I will try rearranging the ```deleteProject``` mixin to solve this and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks that worked, I just had to move the final promise which deletes the images to the top. Can I ask what the benefit of using ```Promise.all()``` is. It seems to be slower when I use it than when I dont (maybe just coincidence)

Comment: @TomWalsh We use `Promise.all()` to execute in parallel a set of asynchronous operations that return a Promise.  Since we don't know we cannot chain the upfront the size of the `querySnapshot` we cannot chain them with the `then()` method like we do with the other ones. So we use `Promise.all()` to be sure all of these asynchronous operations are completed.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to return the **foremost** `.then()` in the Promise chain of this `deleteProject` method, and any subsequent call should be able to pick it up from this point.

```js
deleteProject() {
  // Add a return keyword here, or assign the Promise to a variable and return it. 
  return firebase.firestore().collection('years').doc(yearId).collection('projects').doc(projectId).get()
        .then( /* removed for brevity */ )
}
```

The calling method,

```js
methods: {
  del() {
    this.deleteProject(this.yearId, this.projectId).then(() => {
      this.$emit('reload')
    })
  }
}
```

Or, make it "prettier" with the `async` keyword,

```js
methods: {
  async del() {
    // You probably want to do try-catch here as well.
    await this.deleteProject(this.yearId, this.projectId);

    this.$emit('reload');
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the help, this definitley helps me to understand async better. However, this hasn't solved my issue. The ghost element still remains in the DOM for the deleted document, and only when manually reloading is it removed.

Comment: What does this `reload` event do?

Comment: I have updated the question to show the reload function

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Firestore, but it seems like the problem is not in the `loadProjects` function indeed, I suspected the image removal, can you confirm if it does what it's supposed to? As for the Promise `awaiting` part, the above hint should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyways, all functions work correctly they just seem to fire at incorrect times. I had a few issues with firestore documents deleting before storage files which I resolved so I assume the problem is that firebase is not returning promises on completion of tasks in the way I'm expecting it to.